# Command not able to process in cygwin prompt

Tags: cygwin

> In windows XP i have written below .bat file

```
@echo off

C:

set command="sh run_test.sh ff dd 1.sum"

SET mypath=%~dp0

c:\cygwin\bin\bash -c "cd '%mypath%'; export CHERE_INVOKING=1; exec /bin/bash --login -i;"

c:\cygwin\bin\bash -c command
```

> When i run this .bat file, cygwin tool prompt opened but not able to
>   process my cmd "**sh run_test.sh ff dd 1.sum**"

What changes do I need to make to execute this smoothly?

Comment: The two bash commands are executed as seperate processes. This means that the `cd` in the first bash command is forgotten by the time the 2nd bash command runs. Try appending ` %command%` at the end of the 1st  bash command and remove the 2nd bash command so everything is processed in one bash process.

Comment: Tried as per your inputs, but not working same result.. cygwin cmd prompt opened but command is not processing

c:\cygwin\bin\bash -c "cd '%mypath%'; export CHERE_INVOKING=1; exec /bin/bash --login -i; %command%;"